# Transferring objects from one Winform to antoher C#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-5

I have a quite interesting problem...

I have one **Form** on which I have a datagridview. From this datagrid I select an object (in my case a medicine ) and when I clik on the button "Create reciept" I'm calling my other **Form** called "New Recipet" and it sticks to that form datagrid

The problem is now that I want to transfer more objects in one "session" like more items on one Receipt Form.

Here is the code on FORM1

```
private void btnIzdavanjeRacuna_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   hzzoLijekovi selektiraniLijek = hzzoLijekoviBindingSource.Current as hzzoLijekovi;
   if (selektiraniLijek != null)
   {
      using (var db = new appotekaDBEntities())
      {
         var lijekApoteka = (from l in db.lijekovi
                             where l.serijskiBroj == selektiraniLijek.serijskiBroj
                             select l).SingleOrDefault();

         if (lijekApoteka == null)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Lijek ne postoji u bazi", "Upozorenje");
         }
         else if (lijekApoteka.kolicina == 0)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Lijek ne postoji trenutno na zalihi", "Upozorenje");
         }
         else
         {
            FormRacuniNovi noviRacunForma = new FormRacuniNovi(lijekApoteka);
            noviRacunForma.Show();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Sorry, its on Croatian language , but you should understand the logic. So... everything works for on item or object

On the other FORM" I have

```
private lijekovi lijekNaRacun;
public FormRacuniNovi (lijekovi lnr)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   lijekNaRacun = lnr;
}

private void FormRacuniNovi_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lijekoviBindingSource.DataSource = lijekNaRacun;
}
```

I think I should probably transfer a binding list but lets say I want to transfer one by one item because otherwise its to complicated (I have a few other queries before I get to the datagrid I want to transfer on FORM1)

How should I solve this problem?

On the second FORM , or the form on which I want to have multiple items in the datagrid I should probably have a bindinglist, but then I have a conversion problem when transfering a **.SIngleOrDefault()** object...

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking how to send multiple objects over to a new form, but one at a time? As in you don't want to pass everything to the constructor of the new form? p.s. Croatian is seriously interesting looking.

Comment: Yes exactly, When I click on the datagrid on the FIRST form i send the first object and with that construct the second form, than later on send more objects ( as I click in the datagrid table) but still append it to the second form datagrid, all on the same one

Answer (score 0):

I think this must do ;

Change New Recipet form's constructor like this :

```
Form1 frm;
public New_Recipet(Form1 sender)
{
    frm= sender;
}
```

Create a function on Form1.cs :

```
public void CreateRec(string argThatYouNeed,string anOtherArgThatYouNeed)
{
    //Do Whatever You Want With Args
}
```

and on submit button in Recipet form :

```
frm.CreateRec(arg1,arg2);
```

Comment: That would be okay if I have fixed arguments, but what if I select them from a Datagrid (table) that can have 1,2,3 or more rows which Im transferring?

Comment: @user3732071 For that you can pass selected rows item array to other form.Or you can write a class for your needs and pass it as a paramater

Comment: Yes that will do the trick! Could you help me with a another problem i have encounterd -> adding multiple selected items to a binding list? Here is the snip : http://i.imgur.com/WIYsPoi.png . I want to add current items I click to a binding list and then transfer the whole list further

Comment: ^^ Found the problem - I have been transferring ToList() to bindingList

Comment: @user3732071 Sorry for late.I'v been working.I'm glad it worked ^_^